# Select data from JSON

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I am stuck at how to select a value from JSON.

Table **Inventory**:

```
Name   | Json_Column
-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
Ball   | [{"skuId":"1","quantity":1,"skuName":"$5 valley ball"},{"skuId":"2","quantity":1,"skuName":"$10 BasketBall"}]
Racket | [{"skuId":"3","quantity":1,"skuName":"$5 Badminton racket"}]
```

I want to convert the following result using select SQL statement to:

```
Name   | Json_Column
-------+---------------------------------------
Ball   | $5 valley ball, $10 BasketBall
Racket | $5 Badminton racket
```

When I use this SQL statement to select, it returns null; I need some help for the SQL.

```
select JSON_VALUE (Json_Column, '$.skuName') as Name 
from Inventory
```

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you running against? JSON support is pretty new....

Comment: Hi @marc_s I am using SQL Server v17.7 to query the `skuName` (from Json_column) and `Name` from table Inventory, but I couldn't get it.

Comment: Here is the site I references https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5374/transforming-json-data-to-relational-data-in-sql-server-2016/, but I still have some error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(Json_Column, '$') 
WITH (skuId int'$.skuId',quantity int '$.quantity',skuName varchar(50) '$.skuName')
```

**Update**

Okay, so to select from the table you can do cross apply with OPENJSON

```
SELECT skuName from Inventory
CROSS APPLY
OPENJSON (Json_Column)
WITH (skuId int'$.skuId',quantity int '$.quantity',skuName varchar(50) '$.skuName')
```

Comment: I quite confused that where can I query from table `Inventory`? Because the column Name and Json_column is in the table `Inventory`

Comment: Currently my sql return multiple rows, so I think OPENJSON are not working in my situation, I understand that I need set @json to json_column.

Comment: @PokemonPro, Okay, I will update my answer in a moment.

Comment: Alright, I got it after applying `CROSS APPLY`, Thank you very much.